# Understanding the Role of Member Device in Cisco 3850 VSS Stack

Tags: cisco, network, stacking, vss, cisco-3850

***Clarifying the Role of Member Device in VSS Domain Configuration***

I am trying to understand the role of a device in a VSS domain as a "member."

> What does it mean for a device to be a member?

---

```
lan-dsw show switch

Switch/Stack Mac Address : 94d4.69e7.7f00 - Local Mac Address

Mac persistency wait time: Indefinite

Switch   Role    Mac Address     Priority Version  State

------------------------------------------------------------

 1       Member   94d4.69e7.7f00     15     V02     Ready

 2       Standby  0059.dc07.1c80     14     V02     Ready

*3       Active   0087.31fe.8780     1      V02     Ready
```

---

> The Cisco website says that a stack can consist of 9 devices, but basically these are two participants, the main one and the standby i.e. as I understand it, the 3rd participant is added here simply for redundancy and increasing the capacity of the ports?

> How many devices are included in a Cisco 3850 VSS stack?

> How does a member device in a VSS stack contribute to the performance of the network?

Comment: VSS is different than stacking.

Comment: member: one of the individuals composing a group. Additional switches always add capacity. Redundancy is only possible if a node is connected to more than one stack member. (and often not even then. see also: the "split brain" problem)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  Switch number one is neither the active or the standby.

If switch 3 were to fail, switch 1 would become the new standby.